# StartUpdateLocation during a didreceiveremotenotification:fetch

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, ios7, fetch

Good evening everyone !

I have a simple question : How to enable [CLLocationManager startUpdateLocation] when I receive a correct push notification using didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetch on iOS 7 ?

Right now, I have :

```
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    if ([userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] && [[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"content-available"])
    {
        if ([userInfo objectForKey:@"update-location"])
        {
            [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(handleLocationNotificationPush:) withObject:completionHandler];
        }
        if ([userInfo objectForKey:@"update-sensors"])
        {

        }
    }
}

-(void)handleLocationNotificationPush:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    [CLController.locMgr startUpdatingLocation];
    ++nbPushReceive;

    [self.pushLockForLocation lock];
    if ([self.pushLockForLocation waitUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:25]] == TRUE && self.lastKnownLocation != nil)
    {
        [self.pushLockForLocation unlock];
        // Send my new location to server using HTTP request
        [self sendLocationForPushUpdates:self.lastKnownLocation fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];

        if (![UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive)
            // it stops location updates
            [self stopAllLocationUpdates];
        return;
    }
    // In case we didn't receive any new position during 25 secondes
    [self.pushLockForLocation unlock];
    if (![UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive)
    {
        [self stopAllLocationUpdates];
    }
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
}


- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location
{
    NSLog(@" *** LocationContrller - LocationUpdate location");

    self.lastKnownLocation = location;
    if (location.horizontalAccuracy < 500)
    {
        [self.pushLockForLocation signal];
    }
}
```

Of course, my CLController delegate is the same class (location updates work when application is in foreground). In my plist.file, I have the "Remote notifications" checked.

I am missing something ?

Thanks for your help ! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to myself, and using severals stackoverflow's posts, it's apparently impossible to re-active the location update when you're in background. To keep being updates of your location updates, you have to let it run even if you're going in background !!

:)

Answer (score 2):

This could be related to the fact that in iOS7 enabling Location Services whilst in the background does not give you unlimited background processing time as it did in previous iOS version. Check out the WWDC 2013 What’s New in Core Location video at around 5 minutes 30. Therefore your app gets suspended again around 30 seconds after receiving the push notification.

I have a similar problem which as yet I've not found the solution to. However if you'd like to get to the same place I am try the following -

Firstly put an NSLog in didReceiveRemoteNotification, run your app on the device, put it into the background and send it a push notification. If you see your NSLog you'll know that the content-available flag is set correctly in your push.

Next add an NSLog in -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations. If this gets hint then you know that you are indeed enabling location services.

If you get this far you've probably got the same problem I have. 30 seconds isn't always long enough to get a location to the accuracy I want it.

BTW if you're using an iPhone 5 or newer you can use deferred location and keep location services running constantly. Sadly I need it to work on an iPhone 4s.

UPDATE -
I've now found that this is specifically related to background push notifications and didReceiveRemoteNotification. Enabling Location Manager from a standard background task will work as it did before iOS7. Therefore you can still use background tasks together with Location Manager to get your position every x minutes, you just can't start the whole thing off using a background push.

Comment: My logs seems to be good, but locationUpdate get never fired =/ I guess, as you said, 30 isn't enought..

Comment: @jonC: hi,It would be great if you post some code related to `didReceiveRemoteNotification` with background task.I am stuck in this so long. please help me. :)